# Data Flow source in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my Source table in Data Flow I have 44840 rows. I can see it in the Data preview tab. After running the pipeline successfully I look at the details of the run (the glasses symbol) and notice that the source has double amount of rows: 89680. Why this inconsistency?

Comment: Did you run the debug again?

Comment: @Joseph Yes, I restarted the debug. Did not help.